# Application of universal property of module direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, universal-property

I am reading Grillet's "Abstract Algebra" and I am confused about the application of the Universal property of the Module direct sum. The universal property is given by prop 3.2 in the book. [image]

One of the results of this proposition is the homomorphism between the direct sum.
[image]

I understand we can prove this result directly without using the universal property. But I wonder how does the universal property imply this result. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just apply the universal property to the family of module homomorphisms $A_i\longrightarrow\bigoplus_{i\in I}B_i$ given by $\kappa_i\circ\varphi_i$.